# Prove $\int_1^\infty f< \infty\implies \int_1^\infty f^{3/2} < \infty?$

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

So it's given that 
$f(x)>0$ for all $x$, is differentiable everywhere, decreases, and $\int_1^\infty f(x) \mathrm{d}x$ converges. How do we then know that $\int_1^\infty f(x)^{3/2} \mathrm{d}x$ converges?

I suppose just looking at it is possible to guess that it would converge, based on the graphical representation of the function's Riemann sum, but I'd like a more rigorous explanation if possible.

Secondly, how would we know that
$\displaystyle\int_0^1\ f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \mathrm{d}x$ always converges? I suspect this would have something to do with the fact that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\infty$, but I'm not too confident about this.

Comment: This is because $g = f^{1/2}$ is bounded. If $\int |f| < \infty$ and $\sup|g| < \infty$, then $\int |fg| < \infty$.

Comment: "differentiable" is an unnecessary hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)$ must converge to zero as $x \to \infty$ for the integral to be defined.  Given that, there is some $M$ so that $x \gt M \implies f(x) \lt 1$.  In that region, $(f(x))^{3/2} \lt f(x)$ so the integral of $(f(x))^{3/2}$ is monotonically increasing and bounded above.  It therefore converges.  A big part of the message is that convergence only depends on what happens "near infinity".  Anything that happens below $M$ can change the value of the integral, but not whether it converges.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $f$ decreases and its integral from $1$ to $\infty$ converges, then there must be a point $x_0$ where, for all $x>x_0$,

$$f(x) < 1.$$

What can we say about $f(x)$ and $f(x)^(3/2)$ when $f(x)<1$?

For the second one, the substitution $x\to 1/x$ may be useful.

Comment: How can I deal with the $\mathrm{d}x$ for the second one if I use the suggested substitution?

Comment: If $y=1/x$, $x=1/y$, so $dx=-\frac{1}{y^2} dy$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is decreasing, so $f(x)\leq f(1)$ for all $x\geq 1$ and hence $\sqrt{f(x)}\leq \sqrt{f(1)}$ for all $x\geq 1$ as well, then $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)^{3/2}dx=\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\sqrt{f(x)}\leq\int_{1}^{\infty}\sqrt{f(1)}f(x)dx=\sqrt{f(1)}\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx<\infty$, no differentiability is involved.